# 'Go To Definition' greyed out in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, metadata, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 on 2 machines. When I open the same project on both machines and open the same codebehind, if I right click a method call, 'Go To Definition' is greyed out on one machine but not the other. This is for any method call in a referenced assembly. Methods in the current code behind work fine. The machine it doesn't work on is a clean build.

Did I miss installing something?

Comment: Which proggramming language is this?

Comment: does anything in this [Microsoft Forum Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5562f8f3-8fee-4080-83c1-7dbba8dadd4a/go-to-definition-is-disabled-in-visual-studio?forum=csharpide) help?  Just as a reminder since they talk about deleting your SUO or user file make a backup of it before you do.

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı - It's C#.

Comment: @MarkHall - Just tried that and there is no change.

Comment: Some people tell that they have solved by deleting suo files and rebuild

Answer (score 5):

Same issue. I simply right-clicked the project and performed an Unload Project. Reloaded it, and Go To Definition is working again.

Comment: I was re-installed the vs2013 using setup file. Was n't working with that solution. Actually this answer worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I did face it once before. Steps I followed after which it started to work for me:

1. Right Click on solution and run "Clean Solution".
2. Right Click on Solution and run "Rebuild Solution".

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you also need the microsoft sql server compact 4.0 for intellisense to work.

Answer (score 0):

Closing all of the open files in Visual Studio and opening them again from the Solution Explorer fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have face this issue while upgrading from vs 2012 to vs 2013.  when you open the vs.2012 to solution into the 2013 then go to definition was not working.

I have solved it by creating new project in the vs.net 2013 and added all the objects back to the solutions. it is working without any issues now.